# Plotly xlabel and ylabel names are cropped how to make them appear full?

Tags: python, pandas, plotly

I was trying to create some heatmap using `plotly3.10` and I encountered one problem that the
column names are not displayed full in ylabel.

```py
import pandas as pd
import plotly.figure_factory as ff
from plotly.offline import plot, iplot, init_notebook_mode
df = pd.util.testing.makeDataFrame()
df.columns = ['this_is_long_column_name','another_column_name','yet_another_column_name','price']
df_corr = df.corr()
z = df_corr.values
fig = ff.create_annotated_heatmap(z,showscale=True,
                                  x=df_corr.columns.values.tolist(),
                                  y=df_corr.columns.values.tolist()
                                  )

iplot(fig)
```

I got this image:
[image]

## Question

1. How to show the full column name in ylabels?
2. How to show xlabel on both top and bottom with larger fontsizes?
3. How to show only 2 significant numbers,  like `df.round(2)` only in plot?

Comment: 3. `z.round(2)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might work for you:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

import plotly
import plotly.offline as py
import plotly.graph_objs as go
import plotly.figure_factory as ff
from plotly.offline import plot, iplot, init_notebook_mode
init_notebook_mode(connected=False)



df = pd.util.testing.makeDataFrame()
df.columns = ['this_is_long_column_name','another_column_name','yet_another_column_name','price']
df_corr = df.corr()
z = df_corr.round(2).values
fig = ff.create_annotated_heatmap(z,showscale=True,
                                  x=df_corr.columns.values.tolist(),
                                  y=df_corr.columns.values.tolist()
                                  )

layout = go.Layout(margin=dict(l=200, r=50, t=100, b=50))
fig.layout.update(layout)

iplot(fig)
```

Gives:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried manually specifying the margins? E.g.:

```
import plotly.graph_objs as go

layout = go.Layout(
    margin=dict(l=80, r=80, t=100, b=80)
)
```